# Java Buffer Strategy causes severe lag

Tags: java, java-2d

I have a small engine that runs well on my OSX laptop, but runs crashes or lags severely when ran on a less powerful Linux PC. I minimized the code the point where it's just one small class, but the exact same lagginess is there. I think it has something to do with the Buffer Strategy and threading. Here's the class:

```
public class Test extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    public Test()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Test();
    }

    public synchronized void start()
    {
        this.thread = new Thread(this);
        this.thread.start();
        this.running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop()
    {
        try
        {
           this.thread.join();
           this.running = false;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(running)
        {
            render();
        }
    }

    private void render()
    {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null)
        {
            this.createBufferStrategy(2);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone else reading this, it's not a good idea to mix Swing lightweight and AWT heavyweight components.  If you want to draw in a Swing application, use a JPanel.

Comment: Would it be recommendable to use AWT over Swing if creating a 2D game?

Comment: No.  See my answer for an example graphics application using Swing.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the delay before the Canvas was painted black.  You have to paint something on the Canvas before you set the JFrame visible.

Here are the changes I made to your code.

1. I used a JPanel instead of a Canvas.  I get automatic double buffering with a JPanel.
2. I started the Swing application with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  This puts the creation and execution of the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).  Oracle and I insist that all Swing applications start this way.  Later in this explanation, you'll see why this is critical.
3. I paint a white image and then a black image every 250 milliseconds.  This way, I'm sure that the painting code is working.
4. I moved the thread code into it's own class.  I had a problem where a boolean was being used by the thread and the JPanel  By putting the thread in its own class, I could create separate booleans for the thread and the JPanel.
5. In the JPanel paintComponent method, I painted something before I set the JFrame visible.
6. I set the preferred size of the JPanel, rather than the size of the JFrame.  I want to  know the size of the drawing panel, anyway.
7. In the thread code, the method calls to the drawing JPanel are placed inside of a SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  This ensures the painting happens on the Event Dispatch thread, while the timing loop executes in a different thread.  This ensures that the GUI remains responsive.

Here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DrawingTest extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2584117430541789858L;

    private DrawingTestRunnable drawingTestRunnable;

    private boolean isWhite;

    public DrawingTest() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 700));
        this.isWhite = true;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DrawingTest();
            }
        });
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        drawingTestRunnable = new DrawingTestRunnable(this);
        new Thread(drawingTestRunnable).start();
    }

    public boolean isWhite() {
        return isWhite;
    }

    public void setWhite(boolean isWhite) {
        this.isWhite = isWhite;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (isWhite) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        g.dispose();
    }

    public class DrawingTestRunnable implements Runnable {
        private boolean isWhite;
        private volatile boolean running;

        private DrawingTest drawingTest;

        public DrawingTestRunnable(DrawingTest drawingTest) {
            this.drawingTest = drawingTest;
            this.running = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long duration = 250L;
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (running) {
                repaintPanel();
                long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                long loopDuration = Math.max((duration - elapsedTime), 5L);
                sleep(loopDuration);
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }

        private void repaintPanel() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    drawingTest.repaint();
                    isWhite = !isWhite;
                    drawingTest.setWhite(isWhite);
                }
            });
        }

        private void sleep(long duration) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(duration);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }

        public synchronized void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.running = running;
        }

    }
}
```